# React Tutorial - DOM updates but does not display in browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, dom, browser

I'm following along to the official React tutorial from [here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), and I have come across this bug where I can see that the DOM is updating in my browser inspector, but that change is not reflected in the actual page.

I have tried using `forceUpdate` and calling `setState` in more places, but none of those are changing the behavior, because it seems like the DOM is updating correctly as expected.

If I edit the DOM manually through the inspector, that is drawing correctly to the page too.

Even more puzzling is that the status line changes every click consistently, but the cells act very odd - sometimes appearing or disappearing randomly.

You can see a gif of the problem here:

[image: Gif of the unexpected behavior]

And here is the relevant code (my code is slightly different in structure to the tutorial's):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

// props:
//    - value:   the cell value to display
//    - onClick: the delegate called when the cell is clicked
//
function Square(props) {
    return (
        <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
}

// props:
//    - player:  the string identifier of the current player
//    - onClick: the delegate called when the cell is clicked
//
class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: Array(9).fill(null),
            // history: []
        };
    }

    onSquareClicked(index) {
        const newSquares = this.state.squares.slice();

        // Only handle click if this square is empty
        if(newSquares[index] === null) {
            // this.state.history.push({squares: this.state.squares});

            newSquares[index] = this.props.player;
            this.setState({ squares: newSquares });

            // Notify parent
            this.props.onClick();
        }
    }

    renderSquare(i) {
        return <Square value={this.state.squares[i]}
                       onClick={() => this.onSquareClicked(i)} />;
    }

    render() {
        const status = 'Next player: ' + this.props.player;

        return (
          <div>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
            <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(0)}
              {this.renderSquare(1)}
              {this.renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(3)}
              {this.renderSquare(4)}
              {this.renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
              {this.renderSquare(6)}
              {this.renderSquare(7)}
              {this.renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentPlayer: null
        }

        let isXFirst = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0);
        let startingPlayer = isXFirst ? 'X' : 'O';

        this.state.currentPlayer = startingPlayer;
    }

    swapPlayer() {
        let nextPlayer = 'X';
        if(this.state.currentPlayer === 'X') {
            nextPlayer = 'O'
        }

        this.setState({ currentPlayer: nextPlayer });
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.swapPlayer();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="game">
                <div className="game-board">
                    <Board player={this.state.currentPlayer} onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>
                </div>
                <div className="game-info">
                    <div>{/* status */}</div>
                    <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm using `Firefox 80.0` - restarting the browser has not changed this behavior, updating the browser did not help either.

Let me know if you want me to try different things to provide more information. I am very very stumped on this one.

Update: **However, this does work just fine on Safari...which makes me believe it is a problem with Firefox or the Firefox install on my machine. Will update with more information when I have some**

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour... https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cache-wj6j0?file=/src/index.js (this link won't exist for too long)

Comment: Hmm I don't have Chrome but I realized I could try it on Safari - and it worked on there. It's more information, but not a solution - because it's near impossible to develop using Safari without Firefox/Chrome dev tools :(

Comment: Safari has dev tools... https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/sfri20948/mac

Comment: Yes, sorry - I meant not as feature rich dev tools, also I don't think React devtools has an add-on for Safari

Comment: Thankfully it's available to be run separately so you can use whilst running Safari. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-devtools

Comment: Oh I see - will check it out thanks! Still wish I could figure out the issue with my Firefox though - it is baffling. Tomorrow I'm planning to try uninstall/reinstall or a new profile.

Comment: This is what I don’t get. I ran your code in Firefox and it works.